# how to get dfferent values using the same ID in the mess table in oracle?

Tags: oracle

The table has single row with unique ID, duplicated rows and multiple different rows with the same ID. 

I need to pick up those rows which have different values with the same ID

```
ID    Major  Major_ID
1234    chemi     1111
1234    chemi     1111
673     biology   2222
673     phylo     3333
2480     comput    4444
2480    busine    5555
243     accout    6666
492     finance   7777
4812    engine    8888
```

SQLFiddle with sample data: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

The expected result:

```
ID    Majoy    Major_ID
673    biology   2222
673    phylo     3333
2480     comput    4444
2480     busine    5555
```

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: You may have to add what your desired logic is, your question isn't very clear on what you have and what you want/need.

Comment: this have to write query in oracle

Comment: in the table, it has single row with unique ID, duplicated rows and multiple different rows with the same ID. I need to pick up those rows which have different values with the same ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the COUNT as analytical function, to count the distinct majors for each id, and then select only those that have count more than 1.

```
SELECT id, major, major_id
  FROM (SELECT id,
               major,
               major_id,
               COUNT (DISTINCT major) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS count_
          FROM first_table)
 WHERE count_ > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE AS 
SELECT ID,Majoy,Major_ID 
FROM YOUR_TABLE T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    select null
    From YOUR_TABLE 
    WHERE T.ID=ID AND T.Majoy = Majoy and T.Major_ID = Major_ID 
    GROUP BY ID,Majoy,Major_ID 
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
)
```

The subquery gets the duplicate data. Then i exclude these rows of the resultset with the principal query. The create table as statement creates a new table based on the data from the query like select into in sql server

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Best to give some form of explanation with your answers.  What may seem like an implicit logic in your answer can be lost on someone who could not figure it out in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. The subquery gets the duplicate data. Then i exclude these rows of the resultset with the principal query. The create table as statement creates a new table based on the data from the query like select into in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Id, Major, Major_ID
from First_Table
Minus
Select Id, Major, Major_ID
from Second_Table
```

Comment: what is this "Minus"?

Comment: I misunderstood her question. I did not realized that the second table is the output. Minus is used to get the values of the first table that is not on the second table. 
for reference:
http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php